# What is the expected return of this hypotetical lottery game?

Tags: probability

What is the expected return of this hypotetical lottery game?

There are 60 numbers and you must pick 6 different numbers.
Then they pick 6 numbers (that will be different from each other) at random and if your 6 numbers is equal to those 6 numbers (but dont need to be at the same order) you win $3,500,000$ dollars.
Each ticket cost $3.5$ dollars to buy.

This is a simplified version of mega sena from brazil

Comment: Does the order have to match? And can the numbers be repeated?

Comment: The only way to win is to hit all 6 numbers and the number order dont need to match, to win. Edited the question to add those infos.

Comment: @marinano Do you know the rules for mega sena ? When does the player win, and how much approximately ?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of winning  is 1 / total number of possible outcomes

You're looking for the number of ways to pick 6 numbers at random from 60, I am assuming without considering the order (that is, 1 3 5 7 9 51 is the same as 5 7 9 51 1 3)

This number is equal to $\binom{60}{6}$ so your probability of winning is $1/ \binom{60}{6}$

The expected value of the game therefore is

$$E = \frac 1{\binom{60}{6}} \cdot 3500000 - 3.5\approx -3.43$$

So in average every time you play you lose 3.43 dollars. Don't play.

Comment: To make matters worse, there are no pay-offs except the jackpot. So, in practice, one will very likely win NOTHING.

Comment: The average return (which is the number the OP asked for), is $7$ cents.

Comment: @Peter it's very easy to get that information from this answer (or one can look at yours :-) )

Comment: I only wanted to point that out because it shows how unfair the game would be :)

Comment: The fact that the player loses $3.43$ dollars is not what the game makes very unattractive. Betting 200 dollars in roulette on red would lose more money in the average. But it would make much more sense because the player would have a reasonable chance to win.

Comment: @Peter well now we're entering the field of behavioral economics.. Yes technically you should take the expected value of the utility function of the person, but the choice of the utility function is very subjective. From my point of view the mathematical answer is the expected value You may very well prefer lotteries with the same expected value but different distribution, but that's very subjective

Comment: True, I only mentioned that because of the final suggestion "Don't play."

Answer (score 1):

The expected return is $$\frac{3.5\cdot 10^6}{\binom{60}{6}}\approx 0.07$$ , which is very low compared to $3.50$. As Ant pointed out, that would mean
an average loss of $3.43$ dollars per game.

Moreover , only the jackpot allows a win, so in practice, one would very likely win NOTHING, making the game very unattractive.

The probability of winning would be $1 : 50,063,860 $

Comment: @hardmath Better ?

Comment: In my opinion, yes.  The OP would probably get the drift of your original post, but this wil benefit casual Readers.